# Scraping Javascript variables to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, parsing, xpath

I'm trying to parse some HTML with Xpath but am finding out the the links I want to get are generated by some javascript and not using just a normal a anchor. The javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Hyperurl="ab5";
    var Hyperlink="46439157";
</script>
```

Now, I've used XPath to grab the script code via:

```
$xpath->query('//script[contains(.,"Hyper")]');
```

Which returns:

```
var Hyperurl="ab5";var Hyperlink="46439157";
```

My question is. How do I get this data into an array much like parse_url or the like? Should I just preg_match_all the variable storing the string? If so, what regex would I use? Or is there a better way to parse and grab the data I want?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
preg_match_all('/"(.*?)"/', $variables, $array);
```

I think your variables would then be $array[1] and $array[2].

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. I really need to get better with regex. I always need help with it

Answer (score 2):

You could use this

```
preg_match_all('/var\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*(["\']?)(.*?)\2;/i', $js, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` will contain the variable names, and `$matches[3]` will contain their values.